# Invoke a server having sniffed a communication

Tags: linux, unix, protocols, netcat

I'm reverse engineering a server service, I sniffed the traffic between the client and the server, here the data packet in hex format:

00000016444f3939393930303030313030315c4a303039333331

It's a TCP server (without authentication and ssl) i want to invoke it using a general client (like nc netcat), but I cannot find a way to send properly the data that i sniffed.

Is there any suggestion or point to look in a deeper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the data into a file in *binary* format, then just do

```
$ cat YOUR_FILE | nc SERVER_IP SERVER_PORT
```

Comment: I solved it using your command but I had to save the packet in raw format not in hex...

Comment: Yes, that's what "binary" means.